# Unable to get property '...' of undefined or null reference just in IE

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

I'm using datatables to display data from Mysql. It's working fine, just lately I have strange problem in Internet Explorer. Every other browser is workign fine.

When I click on any row in the table, row detials roll out and details.php get additional data from the database. In 9 out of 10 cases it's working fine, but sometimes the ticket details will not roll out and in the browser console occur an error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'ERRCLASS' of undefined or null reference

When I click on the same row again, it will roll out everything is fine again.

```
function format ( rowData, row, $chLanguage ) {
   var div = $('<div/>')
   .addClass( 'loading slider' )

   $.ajax( {
     url: 'scripts/details.php',
     langy: chLanguage[0],
     data: {
        name: rowData[0],
        langy: chLanguage,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    success: function ( json ) {
        console.log("json: " + json);
        var childTable = '<div id="rowdetails" class="slidera"><ul class="slider">';
        childTable = childTable.concat(
            '<div class="row rdstyle">' +
               '<div class="col-6 leftcol">' +
                  '<div class="row">' +
                     '<div class="col-6">' +
                        '<span class="be">' + rowData[0] + '</span>' +
                     '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-6 rdtoright">');
'<tr><td><b>Error group:</b></td><td>' + json[0].ERRGROUP);
                            childTable = childTable.concat('</td></tr>' +
                    '</table>' +
...
```

The problem is with the **json[0].ERRGROUP** . When I delete this part, there is no problem, except the missing data which I need of course. Is it possible to rewrite it to work in IE? We are forced to use this browser. Thanks

EDIT:
Here is the json when the row details are working fine:

```
jsontest:  [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
"jsontest: "
[object Array][Object {...}, Object {...}, Object {...}, Object {...}, Object {...}]
{
  0:
   [functions]: ,
   __proto__: { },
   DESC: "Ticket closed",
   CGRPL: "CH Dispatching",
   ERRCLASS: "Hardware",
   ERRDESC: "Ausfall Pin Pad ",
   ERRGROUP: "Kartenterminal",
   nextgroup: "N/A",
   starttime1: "2020-01-03 10:48:44",
   starttime2: "2020-01-03 10:48:44",
   starttimestamp: "N/A",
   Symbol()_m.7dnf1frhcrw: undefined,
   Symbol()_o.7dnf1frhcrw: undefined,
   Symbol(Symbol.observable)_n.7dnf1frhcrw: undefined,
   Symbol(util.promisify.custom)_l.7dnf1frhcrw: undefined,
   ticketno: "11111167"
}
```

When the error 'Unable to get property..' occurs, there is no 'jsontest:' in the browser's console.

Comment: *The problem is with the json[0].ERRGROUP* - yet the error is with a property called ERRCLASS - I think you need to show the result you are getting in that ajax call

Comment: Most likely the problem is that your response simply is either not an array or the backend did not return any data, thus you're trying to access `ERRGROUP` of `undefined`. Please use `console.log(json)` and show us the outcome for the case the error pops up.

Comment: Ok, I added console.log("json: " + json); after the json[0].ERRGROUP and when the problem occurs, there is just "json:" in the console. In all other cases there is something similar to this: "json:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"

Comment: Yes, but we need to see it to help you. BTW try `console.log("json: ", json);` instead.